# Bug reporting tool

Tags: .net

I'm searching for a tool or library that can be connected to an application and keeps track of what the user has been doing: opened windows, actions performed and so on, within the context of an application. Something like log4j or log4net or...

The aim is to attach that information to a stack trace, platform useful information and all that and help us to fix bugs.

Is there such an application?

What I want is not a bug tracker; I know a lot about lots of them: Jira, Mantis, Bugzilla, OnTime, VersionOne, Rally...

What I really want is some software that "attached" somehow to my application does the same (well not the same because it's amazing, so let's say "does its best") as VisualStudio 2010 Ultimate IntelliTrace feature, or something like Firefox, Thunderbird or even Windows when something goes wrong.

Something like showing a dialog to the user to send a report of the crash or eventual error including the message and stacktrace (of course), and additionally a description of the steps followed that led to that situation.

That'd be really great.

Of course we could develop that in our application, but if there's something out there already done and working fine...

Answer (score 0):

I know that [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) manages to attach itself to a running process in order to debug (wpf) bindings and events. While not exactly the tool you're looking for, maybe you can check out the source how it does it and make something out of that?

You didn't specify if this is for WinForms or WPF, so I assumed the latter.

Comment: It's a WinForms application; I'll take a look into it, many thanks!